# Problem converting tensorflow saved_model from float32 to float16 using TensorRT (TF-TRT)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorrt

I have a tensorflow (version 1.14) float32 SavedModel that I want to convert to float16. According to https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/tf-trt-user-guide/index.html#usage-example , I could pass "FP16" to precision_mode to convert the model to fp16. But the converted model, after checking the tensorboard, is still fp32: net paramters are DT_FLOAT instead of DT_HALF. And the size of the converted model is similar to the model before conversion. (Here I assume that, if converted successfully, the model will become half as large since paramters are cut in half).

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt_convert as trt
import os

FLAGS = tf.flags.FLAGS
tf.flags.DEFINE_string('saved_model_dir', '', 'Input saved model dir.')
tf.flags.DEFINE_bool('use_float16', False,
                     'Whether we want to quantize it to float16.')
tf.flags.DEFINE_string('output_dir', '', 'Output saved model dir.')


def main(argv):
    del argv  # Unused.
    saved_model_dir = FLAGS.saved_model_dir
    output_dir = FLAGS.output_dir
    use_float16 = FLAGS.use_float16

    precision_mode = "FP16" if use_float16 else "FP32"
    converter = trt.TrtGraphConverter(input_saved_model_dir=saved_model_dir,
                                      precision_mode=precision_mode)
    converter.convert()
    converter.save(output_dir)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run(main)
```

Any advices or suggestions are very welcome! Thanks

Comment: Do you get any error log?

Answer (score 1):

You specify the precision mode correctly for TF-TRT. But checking the network parameters on TensorBoard will not reveal how the the TensorRT engine is internally storing the parameters of the converted model model.

There are few things to consider:

- In TF-TRT we still keep the original Tensorflow weights after the model is converted to TensorRT. This is done so to provide a fallback to native TensorFlow execution if for some reason the TensorRT path would fail. This way the saved_model.pb file will be at least as large as the original model file.
- The TensorRT engine contains a copy of the weights of the converted nodes. In FP16 mode, the TensorRT engine size will be roughly half the size of the original model (assuming that most of the nodes are converted). This is added to the original model size, so saved_model.pb would be 1.5x the size of the original model.
- If we set is_dynamic_op=True (default in TF2), then the TensorRT engine creation is delayed until the first inference call. If we save the model before we run the first inference, then only a placeholder TRTEngineOp is added to the model, which does not really increase the model size.
- In TF2 the TensorRT engines are serialized into separate files inside the Assets directory.

Comment: Thanks @Tamas Feher! Quick question about is_dynamic_op: if one of the TRTEngineOp takes in a variable size input, e.g. [4, -1, 4], where the second dimension varies every time. Would you recommend convert it to TRTEngineOp? Would the overhead of creating the engine op each time for different value of the second dimension affects a lot on model inference performance?

Comment: It depends on your requirements. Engine creation overhead can be anything between a few second and several minutes (depending on the model complexity). If you know what shapes do you expect, then you can create necessary engines in advance using TrtGraphConverterV2's build() method (in TF2). Note that in dynamic mode you need to increase the maximum_cached_engines param (default 1), because after we reach this value, then any shape that we cannot handle with the existing engines will be executed in native tensorflow. This way we limit memory consumption and construction overhead of engines.

Comment: We are currently improving support for variable input size models. How much do your input vary in size? Just a few different sizes (eg [4, 4, 4] and [4,8,4]) or you handle a large number of different inputs? Using TensorRT 6 (or newer) we could create engines that support a range of input sizes, and we are currently working on to expose that through TF-TRT.

Comment: Hi @TamasFeher i'm using tf2 and I build the trt engine following the doc here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/experimental/tensorrt/Converter  You said there will be engines serialized to assets directory but I didn't see any. I'm not sure if my model is converted to fp16 or not. How I can check that?

Comment: also for the second point you mentioned about size, what I observed is that no matter I use fp32, fp16, int8, the saved_model.pb files are all 1.5x bigger than the original one. i don't understand why either

Answer (score 0):

Please try by changing:

```
tf.flags.DEFINE_bool('use_float16', False, 'Whether we want to quantize it to float16.')
```

to

```
tf.flags.DEFINE_bool('use_float16', True, 'Whether we want to quantize it to float16.')
```

This should work or give an appropriate error log because with the current code `precision_mode` gets set to `"FP32"`. You need `precision_mode = "FP16"` to tryout half precision.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Ibrahim. I did set --use_float16 when I generate the model. But thanks for answering the question anyway!